# Vzaar API Connection

Tags: php, vzaar-api

I'm working on a project that like youtube but it's about online learning videos. I want to upload, edit and delete video. So I will use Vzaar. Firstly I created a trial account for test and I downloaded Vzaar PHP API on [github](https://github.com/vzaar/vzaar-api-php). I read this [tutorial](https://packagist.org/packages/vzaar/vzaar-api-php?q=). So in this tutorial;

```
require_once 'Vzaar.php';

Vzaar::$token = 'VZAAR_API_TOKEN';
Vzaar::$secret = 'VZAAR_USERNAME';
```

reqired. I'm giving and implement. And then for upload video;

```
$guid = Vzaar::uploadVideo("/path/to/file/video.mp4");
Vzaar::processVideo($guid, "Title", "Description", "labels"));
```

reqired. When I use above code, the oject return null. I didn't connect my account. Help me please! What should i do? Which way should i follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for vzaar and I'm sorry to hear you're having trouble with one of our API libraries. I've tested the php library and confirmed that the code is working as expected.

Please can you ensure you are doing the following, and then try running your code again:

1. You have signed up for a vzaar account and you have generated a read-write API token
2. You are using the token and your username as the API credentials
3. You are replacing the "/path/to/file/video.mp4" with the absolute path to the file you're trying to upload

This should work using the code example you've pasted in your original question.

If you're still having trouble, please kindly contact our support team. They will be able to look at your account and provide more specific, detailed help.

Thanks.